# custom axis width with theme after loading cowplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I am trying to make the X and Y axis lines thicker using `theme(axis.line=element_line(size=2))` but cowplot is overriding it. Is there a way to specify XY axis lines size while using cowplot?

I tried adding `theme(axis.line=element_line(size=2))` to my plot. Cowplot typically respects specifications I pass to `theme`, but not this one.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x=trans, y=cty)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme( axis.line = element_line(size = 2))
# correct plot

########

library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x=trans, y=cty)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme( axis.line = element_line(size = 2))
# ignores size.
```

I would like to manually specify the size (thickness) of axis lines while using cowplot if possible.

Comment: Loading `cowplot` sets the default theme to its own. I don't like this feature about it, and therefore generally don't load the library, just call functions I need from it like `cowplot::plot_grid`

Comment: @Nick: you can go back to ggplot default them by running this line after you load `cowplot`: `theme_set(theme_gray())`

Comment: Thanks @camille and @Tung. I was only using it for the default clean look, so I think I will just use `ggplot2::theme_classic()` instead and separate `cowplot::*` as I need it.

Comment: I suspect `theme(axis.line.x = element_line(size = 2))` and similar for y would work.

Comment: that'll do it. thank you @ClausWilke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the axis (i.e. X or Y) in the call to `theme()` fixes this issue as @ClausWilke pointed out in the comments.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x=trans, y=cty)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(size = 2),
        axis.line.y = element_line(size = 2))
```