# changing axis size in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on a plot where I would like to change the axis thickness to match the boarder of the facet labels. Somehow `axis.line = element_line(color="black", size=0.5)` doesn't work - any ideas why?

This is my code...

```
    ggplot(datgg_final, aes(y = total_GLS, x = timing)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = genotype)) +
    facet_grid(col=vars(genotype)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#0496FF", "#53A548")) +
    ggtitle("Effect of Timing") +
    xlab("Days since Defence Induction") +
    ylab("Total Glucosinolates (µmol g^-1 DW)") +
    theme(strip.background = element_rect(color = "black", fill ="white", size=0.5, linetype="solid"),
        axis.line = element_line(color="black", size=0.5))
```

... and the plot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2kVm.jpg)

Even in most basic plots I cannot change any axis settings (except the linetype), this code just shows the normal boxplot, no red axes, no change in line size:

```
    ggplot(datgg_final, aes(y=total_GLS, x=timing)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    theme(axis.line=element_line(size=0.5, color="red"))
```

Comment: Since a reproducible data is not available, try if this gives you what you want. `ggplot(datgg_final, aes(y=total_GLS, x=timing)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(axis.line=element_line(size=0.5, color="red", linetype="twodash"))`.

Comment: This isn't doing the job, but I found the underlying problem meanwhile. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, this seems to be a simple clipping issue. Unfortunately, this can't be adressed with the normal ggplot interface (as far as I know), but you could mess around in the gtable to produce the plot you want.

Consider the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

g <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~ Species) +
  theme(strip.background.x = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "white", 
                                          size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5))
g
```

[image]

You can see that the apparent linewidths of the facet strips and the axes are unequal. We can turn of the clipping by messing around in the gtable:

```
# Convert plot to gtable
gt <- ggplotGrob(g)

# Find the strips
is_strip <- grep("strip", gt$layout$name)

# Turn off clipping at highest level
gt$layout$clip[is_strip] <- "off"

# Turn off clipping at the strip level
gt$grobs[is_strip] <- lapply(gt$grobs[is_strip], function(strip) {
  strip$layout$clip <- "off"
  strip
})

# Plot
grid.newpage(); grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Now the apparent linewidths are the intended linewidths, but it took quite some extra steps to get there. If somebody has a more elegant solution, be welcome to post an alternative.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it works perfectly well! Just after posting the question (after trying for hours...) I found the underlying problem: I use the cowplot package, which apparently overrides this exact command as it sets its own default theme. Other people found that simply using ```axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.5)``` and similar for y works. Thank you anyway!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244928/custom-axis-width-with-theme-after-loading-cowplot